# Set session and reload page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

First of all, I know that exist a lot of questions and posts saying about session state.

Just to let you know: I use "MasterPager" in my application.

When I set Session("field"), everything is ok. But when I reload my page (when I come back of another page), per example, Session("field") is nothing.

My example.aspx page:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ' It doesn't works, when I reload, Session is nothing
        If Not Session("field") Is Nothing Then
            example.Text = Session("field").ToString
        End If
    End If
End sub

Private Sub ClickButtonActionExample()
    Session("field") = "example text"
    ' It works
    example.Text = Session("field").ToString
End Sub
```

My web.config:

```
<sessionState
  cookieless="UseCookies"
  cookieName=".authz"
  mode="StateServer"
  regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
  stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
  timeout="20"
  useHostingIdentity="true" />
```

Comment: Just to check, you know that the code in your page load will only run once (on first load) and not on subsequent postbacks...

Comment: Yes @Paddy. The error occurs if I per example come back of another page.

Comment: have you turned off cookies in your browser?

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly configured your state server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using cookieless="UseCookies" it requires the client browser to support cookies. If the browser does not support cookies - or cookies are disabled - your session state will not work.

If you set cookieless="UseCookies" cookies will be always used - even if the browser or device do not support them, or they are disabled.

If the device does not support cookies, session information will be lost over subsequent request, because each request will get a new ID.

I think this is what is happening in your scenario.

Comment: Donal, is there any session or whatever that I can use without losing it? Per example, in PHP it is so easy.

Comment: @guinatal Try with this in your web.config instead: <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="10" />

Comment: Donal, it works. But I remember that I had changed to mode "StateServer" because it would be faster. Do you know the vantages about it?

Comment: @guinatal InProc stores the session state in memory - which obviously does not scale well if you have a lot of data stored in sessions or you have lots of users. StateServer is better because it stores state in a service and therefore scales better and is more resilient. There are other options too, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx